# Change to directory where a file is

Tags: linux, bash, find, console

I have the relative path of a file. I want to change to the directory where the file is. Is there any way to do so?

I've tried multiple combinations with "find" but not success.

Comment: If I understand well what you need to do, try `sudo find / -iname "NameOfFile"`. You'll find the file and its path and then `cd` to it.

Comment: Hi @Krackout. That will give you the whole path of the file, included the filename. Changing the directory to a file will give an error, because it is not a directory. Also, with iname you cannot pass "/"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `dirname`:

```bsh
cd "$(dirname "/path/to/file")"
```

or

```bsh
file="/path/to/file"
cd "$(dirname "$file")"
```

---

Using `shell` syntax:

```bsh
file="/path/to/file"
cd "${file%/*}"
```

Comment: Nitpicking: "a file" may be a directory (in POSIX any directory is a file of the type directory). If it's a directory then the path to it may have any number of trailing slashes. "The directory where the file is" is the parent directory. The solution with `dirname` works well in this case. The shell code will `cd` to the file (i.e. to the directory) itself if there's a trailing slash.

Comment: This is the correct solution :)

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh` instead of `bash`:

```
cd /path/to/file(:h)
```

Or:

```
cd -- **/file([1]:h)
```

To look for `file` anywhere (though not in hidden directories unless you add the `D` qualifier) recursively below the current directory, and `cd` to the parent of the first (in alphabetical order; you can use the `o` or `O` qualifier to select a different order) found file.

`:h` is a modifier to get the *head* (dirname) of the file. That comes from `csh` in the late 70s and is also found in `vim` or in `bash` (though only applied to history expansion there). Glob qualifiers (the part inside `(...)` to further qualify or modify globs) is zsh-specific though.

With `bash` and GNU tools, you can do something approaching with:

```
IFS= read -rd '' dir <(
  LC_ALL=C find . -name '.?*' -prune -o -name file -printf '%h\0' |
    sort -z
) && cd "$dir"
```

Or:

```
shopt -s globstar # enable zsh-style recursive globbing though
                  # it's still somewhat buggy in bash
shopt -s failglob

files=(./**/file) && cd "${file%/*}"
```